# What is this white-winged insect from Hong Kong?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

When we were travelling in Hong Kong, near a bushy temple, we spotted some white-wing insects which we had never seen before. I sense it's a type of moth, but I have no idea what classification it is.

1. Tiny to 3-5mm
2. Mostly white on its body
3. Moving slowly
4. High volume in one area
5. Not so sensitive to external threats, e.g. no escaping when you try to hit them.

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think these are planthopper nymphs. I can't be sure of the species, but *Ricania speculum* looks rather similar: 
[image]
([image source](http://www.projectnoah.org/spottings/16896966))